# Weird retain cycle in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

so I have written some codes to better under retain cycle.

```
class AnotherViewController : UIViewController{

var closure : ((() -> Int) -> ())!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    closure = self.someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure

}

func someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure(closure: () -> Int) {
    //        closure()
}
```

}

So apparently, assigning one of the function in viewController to the property closure, it causes the retain cycle problem.

But I don know how?

Self has a strong reference to Closure 
But, does assigning a function in the viewController tp Closure, make a strong reference of self to closure?

Thanks

EDIT ------

Apparently, if you try this in a playground by creating the AnotherViewController, initialize it and assign it to a variable, then set the variable to nil, it will successfully deinit the AnotherViewController, but if you try it in an app, the AnotherViewController will not get deinited.

You can try to add a button to AnotherViewController and dismiss it, for convenience, the button code is this

```
 private func addAButton(){
    let button = UIButton()
    let buttonBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    let buttonCenter = view.center
    button.bounds = buttonBounds
    button.center = buttonCenter

    view.addSubview(button)

    button.backgroundColor = .red

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goBack), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func goBack(){
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: self has strong reference to closure, and closure also hold strong self inside it so it won't release itself after it go out of the function, it will create retain cycle

Comment: @Tj3n which part of the code has the closure been retaining self? That is the part I don understand.

Comment: I ran your code in playground and it appears deinit of AnotherViewController gets called if you set it's instance value to nil

Comment: @avinashpandey thanks for helping.. But you can try it in a singleViewController. After you add a button to dismiss the viewController, deinit is not called

Comment: @progammingBeignner can you please add the code with the button, it will be more helpful.

Comment: @avinashpandey I have added the simple button code in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `closure` is being assigned an *instance* method, which implicitly captures `self`, hence the cycle.

Try the following app:

```
import Cocoa

class Cycle
{
  var closure : ((() -> Int) -> ())!

  init()
  {
     closure = self.someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure
  }

  func someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure(closure: () -> Int)
  {
     print("Hello") // breakpoint on this line
  }
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
  @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
  {
     let aCycle = Cycle()
     aCycle.closure({ 42 })
  }
}
```

Add a breakpoint on the `print` line and run the app.

The app will stop inside `someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure()` which is called by `aCycle.closure({ 42 })`.

Look at the variable display, there is a `self`. This is because every instance method has an *implicit* `self` argument.

In your code where does that `self` come from?

When the line:

```
closure = self.someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure
```

is executed Swift captures the current value of `self` to pass as the implicit argument to `someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure()`, it must do this as you are creating a closure from an *instance* method.

And so you have your cycle, the closure assigned to `closure` contains a reference to `self`.

To see this note the value of `self` when the debugger stops and then select the entry for `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in the stack trace and look at its `aCycle` variable - it has the same value as the `self` of `someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure` - there is your cycle.

In the stack trace you will also see entries like "partial apply" - this is where the supplied argument (`{ 42 }`) and the implicitly captured `self` are collected and passed to `someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure()`.

If you change the code to:

```
  init()
  {
     closure = Cycle.someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure
  }

  static func someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure(closure: () -> Int)
  {
     print("Hello") // breakpoint on this line
  }
```

that is make `someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure` a class (`static`) method instead on an instance one then the current class instance is not captured in the closure and you will not get a cycle.

HTH